# How can I erase duplicated rows for 2d vector in cpp

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2d vector like below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVec_;

   myVec_.push_back({16,0,0,0});
   myVec_.push_back({8,8,0,0});
   myVec_.push_back({8,4,4,0});
   myVec_.push_back({8,4,4,0}); //duplicated
   myVec_.push_back({4,8,4,0});
   myVec_.push_back({4,8,2,2});
   myVec_.push_back({4,4,4,4});
   myVec_.push_back({4,8,2,2}); //duplicated
   myVec_.push_back({4,8,0,4});
```

I want to erase both duplicated rows.

Trying some solutions that I found in StackOverflow didn't work for the second duplicated rows
e.x.

```
 std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8 };
 // 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8

 for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();i++)
 {
     for(size_t j=0;j<v.size();j++)
     {
         if(v[i] == v[j] && i != j)
         {
              v.erase(v.begin()+j);
              j--; // Fix for certain datasets ie: 
         }         //                             1 2 1 1
     }   
 }

 // Produces:
 // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

What is the way to do it?

**Edit:**
I came out with the above solution which looks ok:

```
for(int i = myVec_.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    bool erase = true;
    for(int k = 0; k < myVec_[i].size(); k++) {
      if(myVec_[i][k] != myVec_[j][k]) {
        erase = false;
      }
    }
    if(erase) {
      myVec_.ersae(myVec_.begin() + i);
      j = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I should have mentioned that sorting my vector wasn't ok for my case

Comment: You can use a `std::set` to determine if the data has already been inserted into the vector before you actually add an item to the vector.  Also, `std::unique` requires a sorted vector -- is your vector sorted?

Comment: Also, I know this is sample code, but in a real program, you wouldn't be inserting item into a vector in this fashion (all the items are hardcoded to add one after the other).  Instead, the program you really do have probably needs to *test* if the item is already there, and if it isn't, then insert it into the vector.  That's the part you need to figure out (hint:  `std::set`).

Answer (score 0):

There could be several solutions to this:

---

Solution 1:

Use a `std::set` to determine whether to store the item in the vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

void addItem(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& alldata,
             const std::vector<int>& item, 
             std::set<std::vector<int>>& insertedItems)
{
   if ( !insertedItems.count(item) )
   {
      alldata.push_back(item);
      insertedItems.insert(item);
   }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVec_;
    std::set<std::vector<int>> vectorSet;

    addItem(myVec_, {16,0,0,0}, vectorSet);
    addItem(myVec_, {8,8,0,0}, vectorSet);
    addItem(myVec_, {8,4,4,0}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {8,4,4,0}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,4,0}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,2,2}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,4,4,4}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,2,2}, vectorSet);    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,0,4}, vectorSet);    

    for (auto& v : myVec_)
    {
        for (auto& i : v)
           std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16 0 0 0 
8 8 0 0 
8 4 4 0 
4 8 4 0 
4 8 2 2 
4 4 4 4 
4 8 0 4
```

The `addItem` function basically takes the original vector, the data that will potentially be inserted, and a `std::set` that is populated with the items that have already been inserted.

The `std::set::count` returns `true` if the item is already in the set, otherwise `false` is returned.  The item is only added to the vector if it isn't already in the set.

The drawback is that you need extra space to store the `std::set`.  However the search for the item in the set is much faster than the Solution 2 (below).

---

Solution 2:

The other solution is to add items to the vector, but search the vector for the item before inserting:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void addItem(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& alldata,
             const std::vector<int>& item)
{
   if ( std::find(alldata.begin(), alldata.end(), item) == alldata.end())
      alldata.push_back(item);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVec_;

    addItem(myVec_, {16,0,0,0});
    addItem(myVec_, {8,8,0,0});
    addItem(myVec_, {8,4,4,0});    
    addItem(myVec_, {8,4,4,0});    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,4,0});    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,2,2});    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,4,4,4});    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,2,2});    
    addItem(myVec_, {4,8,0,4});    

    for (auto& v : myVec_)
    {
        for (auto& i : v)
           std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16 0 0 0 
8 8 0 0 
8 4 4 0 
4 8 4 0 
4 8 2 2 
4 4 4 4 
4 8 0 4
```

Since `std::vector` has an overloaded `==` operator, usage of `std::find` can be done to search to see if the item in the vector matches the item that will be inserted.  If there is no match, then the item is inserted.

With this solution, less space is used, since a `std::set` does not need to be maintained.  The drawback is that you have to search the vector linearly, thus taking more time to find the duplicate than if you used `std::set` if the number of items are many.

So if there are many items, this may not be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (and faster) to remove duplicated directly, without using std::set, just std::sort and std::unique (removes consecutive duplicates) :

```
//sorting
{
  std::vector<int>::const_iterator i, j;
  std::sort (myVec_.begin (), myVec_.end (), [&i, &j] (const std::vector<int>& v0, const std::vector<int>& v1) {
    i = v1.begin ();
    j = v0.begin ();
    while ((i != v0.end ()) && (*j == *i)) {
      ++i;
      ++j;
    }
    return i == v0.end ()?false:*i < *j;
  });
}
//unique
auto i (myVec_.begin ());
i = std::unique (myVec_.begin (), myVec_.end ());
if (i != myVec_.end ()) myVec_.erase (i, myVec_.end ());
```